# Color problem with Cossacks: Back to War on Win7/Win 8 64bit

Tags: windows-7, backwards-compatibility, windows-8, cossacks-back-to-war

I have a huge problem with Cossacks: Back to War on:

Windows 7 Ultimate x64 - color problems...I can't fix them by using some ddraw fixes or killing explorer.exe. I tried so much to fix it, but without success.

Windows 8 x64 - When I get in game, the cursor freezes, but not the game because the mouse is working. I can hear sound when I scroll it over menu buttons, and I can use them because it shows me that my cursor is frozen in the middle of the screen.

I had success with DirectDraw hack (ddhack10.zip - you can google it), but with a little problem. Which settings should I use? When I use original halfnhalf settings, it cuts my screen's bottom. By the way, this hack fixed mouse and color problem on both Windows, but it cut off the screen's bottom on both too.

EDIT : Forgot to say, that all my fixes works on Win7 Ultimate x32, but not on these x64 systems.